# Is it acceptable to use the adverb 'now' in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

> Nowadays a variety of kitchen gadgets are **now** available in the market.

In the sentence, is it acceptable to use the adverb 'now' that means 'immediately or at once'?

Comment: *Now* is redundant--you've already expressed this idea with "nowadays".

Comment: The word you want is **readily**. Nowadays these products are *readily* available.

Comment: @StoneyB and TRomano: Your comments would be better as answers. Comments aren't for answering the question.

Comment: I'd like to know whether the meaning of the word 'now' in the sentence can be 'immediately or at once'.

Comment: You could write *"Nowadays a variety of kitchen gadgets are immediately available in the market"* but that reads strangely. Most kitchen shops have lots of items in the shop and they can be purchased immediately. So the word *"immediately"* is redundant. *"Readily"* as suggested in a comment may be slightly better but, again, it seems redundant. What exactly are you trying to say in the test you are writing. If we had some more context, perhaps a whole paragraph, then it may be easier to advise.

Comment: @LMS apparently the unofficial rule for answers in comments is "plagiarize".  Don't hesitate to put the commented answer in an actual answer, and earn points for yourself.

Comment: nowadays actual use for present time,In contrast with past so not need to add again now.

Answer (score 1):

As both StoneyB and TRomano point out in the above comments, the second "now" is redundant, but you can still use other words to express the same concept:

> Nowadays a variety of kitchen gadgets are **readily available** in the market.
>
> Nowadays you **can easily buy** a variety of kitchen gadgets at the market.
>
> Nowadays a variety of kitchen gadgets **have become available** in the market.
>
> A variety of kitchen gadgets **have recently become available** in the market.

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct. You can simply just say "A variety of kitchen gadgets are now available on the market". The "nowadays" is redundant and doesn't really convey the sense of immediacy that "now" does. But if you want to talk less immediately and just talk about in this general time period, then you say "Nowadays, a variety of kitchen gadgets are available on the market". You can use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: You say it is correct but then say you only need one of 'nowadays' and 'now'.  So, you are saying it is not correct.  It is true that you only need one or the other.